# How to update graph in networkx after removing nodes?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I want to update the definition for my graph after removing nodes and edges however when I try to draw it again I get the error that it is missing a node, i.e. the one I removed. 
Here is my example code:

```
a = k(n) #This is a graph function which works fine returning a graph
remove_node = 54
a.remove_node(54) 
nx.draw(a)
```

> > > NetworkXError: The node 54 is not in the graph.

Comment: This code does not produce an error for me.  It will help if you give the complete error message.  But I think the problem is that `a` doesn't have node `54` to begin with, and the error is coming when you try to remove it.  The full error message would make that clearer.